# Accept header in $.ajax() not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have written a generic AJAX request using jQuery and is calling the function from another JS file. The end points are WebAPI actions. I am passing everything like contentType, accept, data and also URL, but even though I am setting the accept type as `application/json`, when we check the Request header in the controller its showing as `*/*`. In chrome's network also, the Request header content type is showing as `*/*`.

```
function Post(url, contentType, accepetType, params, sCallBack, eCallBack, cCallBack) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + authToken); 
        },
        contentType: contentType,
        accept: accepetType,
        data: params
    }).done(function (response) { 
        sCallBack(response) 
    }).fail(function (error) { 
        eCallBack(error) 
    }).always(function (response) { 
        cCallBack(response) 
    });
}
```

When I tried with `XMLHttpRequest` it's working fine for the same endpoint. Can anyone please tell me why this is?

Update :
I tried giving it application/xml and in Network tab of developer tool of chrome its showing */*.

Comment: Could you please include an example of how you call this function and the values you provide to the properties.

Comment: `HttpService.postData(syncSearchURL, "application/xml", acceptHeader, searchQuery, sResponse, eResponse, cResponse);`

Comment: You're setting the contentType to `application/xml` there...?

Comment: am sending content as xml and needed response as json

Answer (score 1):

```
function Post(url, contentType, accepetType, params, sCallBack, eCallBack, cCallBack) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + authToken); 
    },
    header:{"accept": accepetType,"Content-Type": contentType},
    data: params
}).done(function (response) { 
    sCallBack(response) 
}).fail(function (error) { 
    eCallBack(error) 
}).always(function (response) { 
    cCallBack(response) 
});
}
```

Solved my issue. Thanks